# Ubuntu12.10 boots up and hangs

Tags: gnome, boot, updates

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with gnome 3.6. It was working fine. But now after I installed some updates of gnome, I am unable to successfully login into Ubuntu. The Ubuntu boots up normally and after loading the wallpaper it hangs up. Nothing else is shown in the desktop. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is working.

How can I resolve this problem? Is it possible to login into Unity desktop, if gnome has caused this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the login screen you can sign in to Unity. Follow the steps to get logged in fine.

[image]

As you can see, that Ubuntu Logo is circled. Click on it, and you will see this:

[image]

You should see 'Ubuntu'. Select it and click 'OK >'. Then sign in as normal.

Note: Once you click 'Ubuntu' Unity will be your default theme until you change it. To change the theme use the steps above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I am not using a password for login. Its automatic login. So this login screen doesn't appear for me.Can I use some terminal commands to login to unity environment, since only the terminal works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

The same is happening for me...in 3 different machines: my home machine, and 2 machines in my workplace (one of them is a VM).

At home I'm logging in using Cinammon now. It's nice, but it's not what I want, I want gnome-shell.

At work I'm logging into Gnome Classic (no effects).

What I did was open screen terminal 1 (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and `killall gnome-session`. After that the login screen is shown, and then I chose the new default session (either Cinnamon or Gnome Classic with no effects.

Comment: I tried killall gnome-session command. When I executed it I got the log in screen. I tried logging in to Unity as well as the other three gnome options. But in all of them wallpaper loads and hangs. Nothing else is seen. Then I tried log in as a guest user. It was successful on Unity, gnome(with no effects) and gnome(classic). 

When I logged in, I could see the list of the last installations and updates that I have installed. Is there any way to remove those updates? I think some of those updates has created me this problem.

Comment: Hi, this is what I found: there were messages "gnome-shell-cal trap int3" and "gnome-shell.desktop respawning too quickly" in the system log. Following that hint, I tried find something that I had uninstalled that could have caused the problems (I usually try to uninstall everything related to "evolution", for example). In the end, I just **removed "gnome-shell" and re-installed it again** (with "synaptic"). You know what ? **It worked!**